# How to restrict core file size in container on k8s cluster with containerd?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containerd

I want to restrict the size of core file for every container on my k8s cluster.
My k8s cluster is `v1.20` and using containerd `1.5`

I tried to build docker file with command `ulimit -c 0`

But when the container is created and I send a command `ulimit -c` then the reply is `unlimited`

I also tried to mount `/etc/security/limits.conf` on the pod

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf  

\* hard core 0  
\* soft core 0
```

But it didn't work.

I also tried to change containerd's config at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service`
I changed `LimitCore=0` and

```
systemctl restart containerd
systemctl daemon-reload
```

But when I check the `ulimit -c` on the pod, it consistently replies `unlimited` even if I restart the pod.

Please don't ask why do you want to set core file size 0, there are some issues about it.

Let me know if anyone knows the answers  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For self managed EKS worker nodes, run this before running `bootstrap.sh` in your userdata:

```bash
sed -i 's/LimitCORE=infinity/LimitCORE=0/g' /usr/lib/systemd/system/containerd.service
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got to know.....

The order was wrong....

I should have run systemctl daemon-reload and then systemctl restart containerd

Comment: Please update your original question instead of creating an answer commenting the mistake.